# C# how to allow users to input decimals as an answer?

Tags: c#

New to this language and site.
I'm still a bit confused as to the differences between a decimal and a Boolean.

Let's say I have this line.

Console.WriteLine("Enter change.");

I'm not sure what to put after so that it accepts decimals from user input.
I've seen decimal.parse seems to be a common answer but am not sure on how it works.

Comment: Could you add more info to help you?

Comment: Sorry new to this website.

Comment: Please take a moment to visit [ask].

Comment: Your next line of code would be to get input from the user.  Perhaps this tutorial will help you: https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/basic-input-output

Comment: Have you tried `Console.ReadLine();`?

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton thank you so much! I fixed up my question so hopefully it is easier to understand

Comment: @DevinLiu I wish I was near my laptop I will try it later. But, will try it. My goal is to allow users to input the amount of change and then add it with another number later in the code

Answer (score 2):

As very little information was provided here, I'm not sure how long this question will last. Despite this, it seems that you're working on a console app and are probably looking for a `Console.Read()` or `Console.ReadLine()` here. These take user input as a string, but I'd imagine that for currency you would prefer this in a number format. Seeing as it's already cents, I would guess you could do with an int as most people aren't spending fractions of a cent. The code below uses the `Int32.TryParse()` method, which returns a bool value regarding its ability to parse the string to an int, and takes in a string to parse and an int to use as an out parameter. I have enclosed this in a do/while statement to ensure that the user inputs usable data, and is prompted again if this is not the case, followed by an output of the change to provide feedback upon success.

EDIT: It appears that the author is looking for decimal input. The code below now uses decimals instead of integers (I had assumed change in cents rather than change as any money given back post-transaction)

```
bool successfulParse = false;
Decimal change;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter change:");
    successfulParse = Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out change);
} while (!successfulParse);

Console.WriteLine($"Change was {change} cents.");
```

This information is likely readily available elsewhere, and, in the future, it may be valuable to include more information regarding your problem to receive more applicable answers.

Comment: Also, `float.TryParse(string, out float)`

Comment: Ah yes, @DanielPark I see now that the question was edited between beginning and submitting my answer, and the user is looking for a decimal. Post edit to reflect that.